# No way to search multilevel subsite E.g. Demand/Channel

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I need to get the id of a subsite, in microsoft graph api.
I am using the api GET /sites?search={query} 
but in {query} we are able to write only one word.

I am not able to search multilevel sites for e.d Demand/Channel/output

How can I do that in one go?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description you want to search multilevel sites by using the `search` query parameter.

Based on my test, we could not using the `$search` query parameter to search the sites collections.

From [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter),

> You can currently search only message and person collections.

We can use the `filter` parameter to search some site.For example, we can use the following API to search the subsite with name `Demand` in the root site

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites?$filter=startswith(name,"Demand")`// the name start with `Demand`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/sites?$filter=name eq 'Demand'`// the name is `Demand`